# Issue with encoding in Android app pulling data from MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, encoding

I am building an Android app that pulls information from a MySQL db and displays it in the app.
The app has been built using XAMPP to serve the as host for the PHP api files and the MySQL db.
Everything is working perfectly on this development environment.
However when I move it to the production server - Ubuntu Linux, Apache2, PHP5, MySQL - the data pulled from the db is scrambled and unreadable.
The API works fine on the production server through the browser.

For example, I get this response through the browser -

```
{
    "result": 1,
    "patients": [
        {
            "id": "18",
            "patient_id": "123456789",
            "name": "Test Patient3",
            "photo": "img/profiles/chris_palmer_profile_11.jpg",
            "age": "55",
            "race": "Caucasian",
            "blood_group": "O",
            "risk": "Medium",
            "address": "Apt 2A, Some Condo, Some Where, Some City, Some Country",
            "gender": "Male",
            "contacts": "Wife - +44123456789, Doctor - +11234567890, Priest - +661234567890",
            "conditions": "Heart Murmur",
            "current_medications": "",
            "abstinence": "",
            "treatment_preferred": "Royal",
            "allergies": "Nuts, Phenytoin, Penicilin",
            "past_surgical_procedures": "Bypass, Hip, Brain Tumour",
            "immunization": "Measles",
            "insurance_information": "Royal Liver - UK123456789",
            "qrcode": "img/qr/Test Pattient5_25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b_.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

But in the app I get this response -

> ```
>          MRMS1 +_  +$ =0  2-MgǱ  k{  Τ yC7  I~zғ$i r]  "  A =I4r-  <  )  Y\,W p C   ;      G o #      vT j_ (   = > jI _  U@  ޛ ' F | $9
> ```
>
> zcx ./ ( ˙  - k  v@p 1 O  " G    j  ~k       C]   O^GO.N  L fG^,  C? 
>   o@Q  l  KD d iu$  ! 7y  H   ԑ   k   j  a    ƾ X  >zt C  i ! !1W ! C
>   I4 ] 9ɕ78  )t >Y? Dk      ~x 9ḙb - Γ=2&a    l     瑴7p  G ̏ 4 RӖM   U]
>   նn   bYt vQ  |۞   Ͽ _

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update before I close this question.

The problem was that I had not enabled GZip on the production server.